# Contact us form showing invalid form key?

Tags: magento2

When I submit contact us form I am getting invalid key error.It is not hitting the controller file.Please can anyone tell what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

f you are running this Magento site on a local machine (local host) as your question seems to indicate, you may have trouble using the: http://localhost/ syntax, as Magento 2 doesn't fully know how to deal with cookie.

Instead, I'd recommend using http://127.0.0.1/ to access the local site; in this case your browser should be able to recognize this more easily and work with Magento's cookies properly.

You may need to set a cookie domain in the admin area of Magento.

I hope this helps...